# Range Rings in Google Maps V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a script that was written a long time ago and not by me that I have updated from V2 to V3 and I am trying to draw range rings from a centered LatLng point. This worked in V2 but it is not working in V3 and I can't figure out why as I know some of the code is depreciated but not sure what it needs to be replaced with.

```
//Function to draw circles
function doDrawCircle(circleUnits, center, circleRadius, liColor, liWidth, liOpa, fillColor, fillOpa, opts, radials){
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var circlePoints = Array();
    with (Math) {
        if (circleUnits == 'KM') {
            var d = circleRadius/6378.8;    // radians
        }
        else { //miles
            var d = circleRadius/3963.189;  // radians
        }
        var lat1 = (PI/180)* center.lat(); // radians
        var lng1 = (PI/180)* center.lng(); // radians
        for (var a = 0 ; a < 361 ; a++ ) {
            var tc = (PI/180)*a;
            var y = asin(sin(lat1)*cos(d)+cos(lat1)*sin(d)*cos(tc));
            var dlng = atan2(sin(tc)*sin(d)*cos(lat1),cos(d)-sin(lat1)*sin(y));
            var x = ((lng1-dlng+PI) % (2*PI)) - PI ; // MOD function
            var point = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(y*(180/PI)),parseFloat(x*(180/PI)));
            circlePoints.push(point);
            bounds.extend(point);
            if(a==0){
                var offset = new google.maps.Size(-5,0);                                                   //    Added the offset - mile markers look a bit better
                var label = new ELabel(point, circleRadius, "style1", offset, 40);
                map.addOverlay(label);

            }
            if (((a==0) || (a==45) || (a==90) || (a==135) || (a==180) || (a==225) || (a==270) || (a==315)) && radials) {
            //if (((a==0) || (a==45) || (a==90) || (a==135) || (a==180)) && radials) {
                var pline = new google.maps.Polyline([center,point] , liColor, liWidth, liOpa);
                map.addOverlay(pline);
            }
        }
        var poly = new google.maps.Polygon(circlePoints, liColor, liWidth, liOpa, fillColor, fillOpa, opts);
        map.addOverlay(poly);                           // Add a target circle to the map
        map.setZoom(map.getBoundsZoomLevel(bounds));    // This sets the map bounds to be as big as the target circles, comment out if you don't want it

    }

}
```

Then I have this within the `initialize()` function for the map.

```
// You can add circles, or change other parameters
            // radials should be set to true for the maximum distance if you want radials
            // doDrawCircle(circleUnits, center, circleRadius, lineColor, lineWidth, lineOpacity, fillColor, fillOpacity, opts, radials)
            doDrawCircle('MI',llCenter,  62, lcolor, 1, .7, "#FFFF00", 0, { clickable: false }, false);
            doDrawCircle('MI',llCenter, 124, lcolor, 1, .7, "#FFFF00", 0, { clickable: false }, false);
            doDrawCircle('MI',llCenter, 187, lcolor, 1, .7, "#FFFF00", 0, { clickable: false }, false);
            doDrawCircle('MI',llCenter, 249, lcolor, 1, .7, "#FFFF00", 0, { clickable: false }, false);
            doDrawCircle('MI',llCenter, 312, lcolor, 1, .7, "#FFFF00", 0, { clickable: false }, false);
            doDrawCircle('MI',llCenter, 374, lcolor, 1, .7, "#FFFF00", 0, { clickable: false }, false);
//          doDrawCircle('MI',llCenter, 374, lcolor, 1, .7, '#00FF00', 0, { clickable: false }, true);   // This would add the radials
```

This is what it is suppose to look like. This is from the working V2 map.

[V2 EXAMPLE](http://www.mesquiteweather.net/NSGMap/NSGMap.php)

Link to full code

[FULL MAP CODE](http://www.mesquiteweather.net/gmap/nsgmap.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you'll need to do is get the newest version of elabel.js for google maps V3 here:

https://github.com/erunyon/ELabel/blob/master/elabel.js

Then, the good news is you don't need all of that complicated math and stuff which you have going on in your doDrawCircle function. You can now make use of google.maps.Circle as well as the geometry library which must be included via the google maps script tag's url parameters using a 'libraries=geometry' parameter so we can get the text label placement position starting point via google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset. And then I've included a little tweeking of the text placement below to look a bit more tidy.
Test case:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Circles</title>
<style type="text/css">
.style1 {
    /* used for range numbers on rings */
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: verdana, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    background-color:black;
}
</style>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=geometry"></script>
<!-- elabel.js for google maps V3 from here: https://github.com/erunyon/ELabel/blob/master/elabel.js -->
<script src="elabel.js"></script>
<script>

function initialize() {
    var i, meters, options, labelLocation, textLength, textXcenter, label,
         //note I declared the actual font pixel size in .style1 css rule
         //just to help with visualizing the way I'm positioning the label texts
        textPixelSize = 10,
         //will need to invert textYcenter as well as textXcenter to negative numbers later
        textYcenter = (textPixelSize / 2) + 2, //2px tweak for 'y' position, approximation
        mapOptions = {
            zoom: 6,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(32.8297,-96.6486),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
        },
        ranges = [62, 124, 187, 249, 312, 374], //circle radii in miles
        circles = [],
        labels = [],
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
    for (i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
         //convert miles to meters:
        meters = ranges[i] / 0.00062137;
        options = {
            strokeColor: '#FF0000',
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 1,
            fillOpacity: 0,
            map: map,
            center: mapOptions.center,
            radius: meters
        };
        circles.push(new google.maps.Circle(options));//ta-da! easy circles in V3
         //labelLocation will be a google.maps.LatLng object
        labelLocation = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(mapOptions.center, meters, 0);
        textLength = (''+ranges[i]).length;
        textXcenter = (textLength * textPixelSize) / 2; //approximation
        label = new ELabel({
            latlng: labelLocation,
            label: ranges[i],
            classname: 'style1',
            offset: new google.maps.Size(-textXcenter, -textYcenter),//negative will move left and up
            opacity: 100,
            overlap: true,
            clicktarget: false
        });
        label.setMap(map);
        labels.push(label);
    }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:780px; height:600px; margin:10px auto;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT:
Here is revised version which allows to toggle visibility of the rings via the 'Range' button. Also removed all the text label positioning adjustment math and replaced with using style classes for different length texts instead (makes it easier to just use em units in the styles if desired). Added LabelCircle constructor for easier encapsulation and simultaneous control of circles & labels.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Circles</title>
<style type="text/css">
.style1 {
    /*used for range numbers on rings*/
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: .6em;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: verdana, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    background-color:black;
    margin-top: -0.5em;
}
.d2 { /*two-digit numbers on rings*/
    margin-left: -1em;
}
.d3 { /*three-digit numbers on rings*/
    margin-left: -1.5em;
}
/*direct copy of your existing .button style rule*/
.button{
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
        font-weight:bold;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 0 2px 4px;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 0 2px 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 0 2px 4px;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #717B87;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 1px 6px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=geometry"></script>
<!-- elabel.js for google maps V3 from here: https://github.com/erunyon/ELabel/blob/master/elabel.js -->
<script src="elabel.js"></script>
<script>

function LabelCircle(options) {
    this.circle = new google.maps.Circle(options.circleOptions);
    this.label = new ELabel(options.labelOptions);
    this.label.setMap(options.circleOptions.map);
    this.isVisible = true;
}

LabelCircle.prototype.setVisible = function (bool) {
    var method = (bool) ? 'show' : 'hide';
    this.circle.setVisible(bool);
    this.label[method]();
    this.isVisible = bool;
};

//a direct copy of your existing function
function buttonControl(options) {
    var control = document.createElement('DIV');
    control.innerHTML = options.name;
    control.className = 'button';
    control.index = 1;
    // Add the control to the map
    options.gmap.controls[options.position].push(control);
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(control, 'click', options.action);
    return control;
}

function initialize() {
    var i, meters, options, labelLocation, textLength, label,
        mapOptions = {
            zoom: 6,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(32.8297,-96.6486),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
        },
        ranges = [62, 124, 187, 249, 312, 374], //circle radii in miles
        labelCircles = [],
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
    for (i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
         //convert miles to meters:
        meters = ranges[i] / 0.00062137;
         //labelLocation will be a google.maps.LatLng object
        labelLocation = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(mapOptions.center, meters, 0);
         //we'll use textLength below to add a class to the label
        textLength = (''+ranges[i]).length;
        options = {
            circleOptions: {
                strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                strokeWeight: 1,
                fillColor: 'transparent',
                fillOpacity: 0,
                map: map,
                center: mapOptions.center,
                radius: meters
            },
            labelOptions: {
                latlng: labelLocation,
                label: ranges[i],
                classname: 'style1 d' + textLength,
                //offset: //no longer needed, using style classes
                opacity: 100,
                overlap: true,
                clicktarget: false
            }
        };
        labelCircles.push(new LabelCircle(options));
    }
    var rangeOptions = {
        gmap: map,
        name: 'Range',
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT,
        action: function(){
            for (var tmp, i = 0; i < labelCircles.length; i++) {
                tmp = labelCircles[i];
                tmp.setVisible(!tmp.isVisible);
            }
        }
    };
    var rangeButton = buttonControl(rangeOptions);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:780px; height:600px; margin:10px auto;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes thank you, that's perfect! Just a couple of small tweaks. I have a var setting for ranges at the top of this page commented out [NSGMap.js](http://www.mesquiteweather.net/gmap/nsgmap.js) but I am having a hard time assigning it to `ranges = [75, 125, 175, 225, 275, 325], //circle radii in miles` Everything I have tried removes the rings and just shows the miles in the top left. What would be the correct way to apply this. Also what var would I use to define the circles to my button. Here is the map [V3 MAP](http://www.mesquiteweather.net/wxgmap_lightning.php) Thanks!

Comment: I just checked your V3 map and looks like you have the circles and labels working fine. You ask: "what var would I use to define the circles to my button". Not sure exactly what you mean but am guessing you wish to toggle their visibility?? Don't have time at this moment, will be back in a couple hours to post a fiddle perhaps, but remember that each label has a show() and a hide() method, as well as each circle has a setVisible(/*true or false here*/) method as well. I think if I were going to be manipulating, I would actually create a LabelCircle constructor perhaps. Later....

Comment: Thanks that works great! One small issue though is I can't click on icons (markers) on the map unless I toggle off the range rings. Any idea what might cause that?

Comment: In the options you pass to a Marker upon creation, one of the allowed options is a 'zIndex' property, also a Marker object has a 'setZIndex(/*number here*/)' method you may use. In the options you pass to a Circle upon creation, one of the allowed options is a 'zIndex' property. A Circle also has a 'setOptions(/*CircleOptions object here*/)' method which could be used as someCircle.setOptions({zIndex:1}). I think I would pass a zIndex property into each Marker or Circle or Polygon's options upon creating it, and give the circles or polygons lower zIndex's than the markers, and try that.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing and tried that but it is not working. I may not be doing it right. Also the markers are passed via KML file so I added the zIndex option to it as well. Here is the js file [NSGMAP.js](http://www.mesquiteweather.net/gmap/nsgmap.js) is that right?

Comment: Alas, you are right! The Circle objects actually cover the kml layer no matter what, it would seem. It is not an issue with normal markers. But, all you need to do to get around this problem is to pass clickable:false in the options passed to the circles! Then it works and you can click on the kml layer underneath.

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick and works perfectly. Thank you so much for you help! Now on to my last issue.